# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_win32sysloader'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that would at least read aloud upon vocally commanding it. Python 3.10.5, Windows 10 64-bit, error on one of the few lines within importing modules.
Input:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import time
import subprocess
import wolframalpha
import json
import requests
import cv2
engine=pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices=engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice','voices[0].id')
def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()
speak("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.")
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: 'sapi5'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\Desktop\python_version_windows_assistant.py", line 13, in <module>
    engine=pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    from win32.lib import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 128, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 49, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    import _win32sysloader
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_win32sysloader'
```

I fixed another problem before it happened, and I just happened to end up with this error.

Comment: Solved that... now another: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 128, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\Qihua Huang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 114, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    old_mod = sys.modules[modname]
KeyError: 'pywintypes'"

Comment: apparently, it's the sys.modules that causes the hiccup. doesn't include pywintypes

Comment: So, how did you solve the "No module named '_win32sysloader'" issue?